# Command given from the terminal and from php gives different output

Tags: php, terminal, wkhtmltopdf

What is the difference between executing commands from the terminal and from php using system, shell_exec etc?

The reason why I am asking is that it gives different output as I am using the same command to both of them.

The command is

```
"xvfb-run -a -s '-screen 0 1024x768x30' wkhtmltopdf -B 0 -L 0 -R 0 -T 0 --page-height 1147.8px --page-width 1800px --dpi 300 --encoding utf-8 ".$url." /tmp/test.pdf"
```

$url is some url,

Comment: Well, for one, you don't escape the URL. But this question cannot be answered without some additional information: What is `$url`? What output do you get in your terminal? What output do you get in php?

Comment: I cant give the url because of some privacy issues. My question simply is that, is there any difference between them or not?

Comment: well, then replace it with another URL, like `http://example.net`. Test whether the problem persists. If it does, give out that URL. I'm almost certain that that is actually not your question, but let me answer: Yes, there is a fundamental difference between executing commands from terminal and via `shell_exec`: Your terminal is a tty, `shell_exec` not. However, that does not matter here, and is not the problem. Therefore, I'd rather ask the question: `How can I run wkhtml in php`. Beware of the [X-Y fallacy](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).